# How to disable talkback action on a clickable composable item

Tags: android, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable function that displays some text. The talkback is working great as it reads the text. but how can I disable the clickable notification in accessibility for that composable so that I can have a secret click listener to send analytics.

any time I try to add a clickable like this

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable { 
                                                     
        },
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    )
```

When this column is on focus it says 'Double click to activate', and I want to avoid that as there is no user-facing feature on that click.

Comment: Did you try  `modifier = Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics { }` or `Modifier.semantics {this.invisibleToUser()}` ?

Comment: Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics { } didnt work. but the  Modifier.semantics {this.invisibleToUser()} did the trick. thank you .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the [accessibility doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility) you can use the `semantics` properties.
Use the [`invisibleToUser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsPropertyReceiver).invisibleToUser()) property to mark an element to be invisible to the user.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.semantics {
        this.invisibleToUser()}
){}
```