# How to prevent Talkback select and focus some Jetpack Composable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, semantics

In xml, we can simply set `android:importantforaccessibility` to achieve such a goal.
However, in Jetpack Compose, I don't find any similar approach to do so.
Say, if I don't want a `Text()` composable to be selected and focused when Talkback is on, how should I do?

I tried this way but it won't work, as `contentDescription` should be NoNull:

```
modifier = modifier.semantics { contentDescription = null }
```

So then I tried to remove the initial default `semantics` of a Text composable:

```
modifier = modifier.clearAndSetSemantics { }
```

But this won't work too...

The talkback will still try to focus this Text components and read its content.

I also try to manipulate focusProperties() to skip this Text(), but I failed again.

Comment: Check if `Modifier.semantics { this.invisibleToUser()}` works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71037140/2016562